# How to Increment values dynamically in SQL select statement

Tags: sql

I want to display the values A-Z and these values will be auto increment in select statemnet

My output should be Like This

```
Desk A
Desk B
Desk c
....
....
Desk Z
```

I am stuck here

```
Desk No = (Select 'Desk'+'')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Numbers Table: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: What happens after you reach Desk Z?

Comment: after reaching Desk Z again it will be start from Desk A

Comment: Which database are you working on?

Comment: there is insufficient information to produce an answer. what table is used? have you prepared any query at all? is this homework perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, assuming you mean TSQL *and* assuming you have a table from which you're selecting. If you want this independently, you probably want to make a numbers table.

```
SELECT 'Desk ' + CHAR(65 + (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [someColumn])) - 1) % 26))
FROM tableName
```

Of course, it becomes a million times easier if your table just has an `ID` column that has `IDENTITY` set.

```
SELECT 'Desk ' + CHAR(65 + ((ID - 1) % 26))
FROM tableName
```

On the other hand, if you have a numbers table, that's that much easier.

```
SELECT 'Desk ' + CHAR(65 + (value % 26))
FROM Numbers
```

Comment: Iam using T-SQL i want diaplay the desk no based on employees joining and releaving dates.similar to desk allocation .i got ouput 1,2,3 instead of A,B,C by using while loop i got these output.but problem is without using any loops i want to auto generate values in select statement more details see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308321/allocate-and-manage-resources-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment39454951_25308321